# Jenkins git branch to build variable can't have asterisk?

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm having an issue where I've setup a parameterized master build that I have other jobs execute. One of the parameters is a branch I want checked out from git. I've noticed that if I have any asterisks (e.g. origin/hotfix**) in the variable, the checkout falls back to whatever was previously checked out and doesn't actually checkout what I asked it to checkout. This kind of syntax works when I directly enter it into the branch specifier. Any suggestions?